# Mass assign for attr_accessible :association_attributes in special cases

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In the User model I have two accepts_nested_attributes_for: :details (which is has_one association) and :membership_orders (has_many).

For :details I have:

```
attr_accessible :details_attributes
```

But for the membership_orders I can't have so simple accessor, because I want to protect it from the normal user, but make it accessible for the admin.

It's possible to do with attribute-permissions plugin (github.com/Fingertips/attribute-permissions/tree/master), but I think it's not the finest solution.

Can you tell me how I can add special expression for the attr_accessible, or maybe filter out those attributes using before_validation (or what-else).

You can read about this problem by this link: blog.smartlogicsolutions.com/2009/02/24/rails-23-nested-object-forms-im-not-crazy-about-them/

Thanks.

Comment: After several times stuck with that, I've written fully functional rails 2 and 3 solution: https://github.com/dmitry/attr_accessible_block

Answer (score 0):

You could certainly filter them out before validation. Another option is to switch to attr_protected and specify the fields you want protected instead of the ones you want open. That could be a simple switch or a more involved one, depending on the size of your models.

Comment: before_validation realisation:

  attr_accessor :allowed_membership_orders_associations

  def filter_allowed_membership_orders_associations
    self.membership_orders.delete_if { |mo| mo.changed? && !@allowed_membership_orders_associations }
  end

Use of attr_protected isn't good, because: http://railspikes.com/2008/9/22/is-your-rails-application-safe-from-mass-assignment